# Alternative for Angular Areas

Tags: angular, image, coordinates, area

https://github.com/delkant/angular-areas
Link to angular areas which is in angular Js.
Want alternative of this in angular 6 or above.

Basically my requirement is to multiple area selection from an image with co-ordinates.

Comment: Have you implemented something where you are facing error?

Comment: Actually the above link i have give for angular areas full fills all of mine requirement but not compatible for angular other versions.